# knockout js remove does not work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to get my head around observables in knockout js! 
However, I'm facing a problem implementing the remove function on an observable array.

My js is as follow:

```
$(function () {
    var data = [{ name: "name1" }, { name: "name2" }, { name: "name3"}];
    var viewModel = {
        namesList: ko.observableArray(data),
        nameToAdd: ko.observable("name4"),
        myCustomAddItem: function () {
            this.namesList.push({ name: this.nameToAdd() });
        },
        myCustomRemove: function () {
            console.log("before + " + this.nameToAdd());
            this.namesList.remove(this.nameToAdd());
            console.log("after + " + this.nameToAdd());
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

and my html is:

```
Name To add/remove <input type="text" data-bind="value: nameToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'listTemp1', foreach :namesList}">

</ul>
<p>
    <button data-bind="click: myCustomAddItem">Add Item</button>
    <button data-bind="click: myCustomRemove">Remove Item</button>

    <script id="listTemp1" type="text/html">
        <li data-bind="text:name"> </li>
    </script>
</p>
```

my myCustomAddItem works fine, but not the myCustomRemove. I also have put a console.log before and after the `this.namesList.remove(this.nameToAdd());` to see if anything's wrong there, but I cannot see any error in there. When I click the "Remove Item" button, firebug console shows the logs but the item's not removed from the list.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter to `remove` should be a function which returns true or false on whether to remove something.

It works quite similarly to the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

In your case, something like this should work:

```
myCustomRemove: function () {
    console.log("before + " + this.nameToAdd());

    var nameToAdd = this.nameToAdd();
    this.namesList.remove(function(item) {
        //'item' will be one of the items in the array,
        //thus we compare the name property of it to the value we want to remove
        return item.name == nameToAdd;
    });

    console.log("after + " + this.nameToAdd());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[this should be a comment on Jani answer, but I can't still comment on others post, sorry]
Just a small clarification: technically you can call remove() passing the element to remove, see section "remove and removeAll" on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html.

the problem with  your code is that the elements in 'data' array are objects (containing a property called 'name'), and you are asking to remove from the array the string "name4" (or whatever 'nameToAdd' contains).

You can be tempted to create a new object to pass to remove, like this:

```
// old code
//this.namesList.remove(this.nameToAdd());
this.namesList.remove({ name: this.nameToAdd() });
```

but this still fails, because the way javascript object equality works (see, for example: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)).

So, in the end you need to use the function anyway.

In this simple example, you can also convert the 'namesList' array to a simple array of strings, and bind "$data" in the template. see http://jsfiddle.net/saurus/usKwA/.
In a more complex scenario, maybe you can't avoid using objects.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment.It really helps understanding what's going on now :)

Answer (score 0):

[observableArray].remove(function(item) { return item.[whatever] == [somevalue] ; } );